# Copy MariaDb database with selected data

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, backup

I have the shop live database. I need to have opportunity to  make copies of this database but with orders data only for last 14 days. Database can be really big but almost 80 percent of data is order, payment and related tables. So we want to copy only last 14 days data of these tables, and all data of another tables. How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like a classic ETL job. You could use any programming language (like Python) or [KNIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KNIME) that reads from the source db (with an SQL query with a WHERE clause  like `your_date_column >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY`) and write to a sink db.

You can then run it as a (cron) job in Windows/Linux and create each day a backup for the last 14 days but make sure that you also delete/drop the older backups if the size of the backups gets to big.